# Firefox extension inject script before loading any page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've written an Firefox extension to inject some script and css to all web pages loaded while this extension is installed.

Up to now, everything works fine. As soon I open a new page it loads en the script and css are injected. But what I want is that the extension is loaded before the page.

Example; I'm loading the [twitter intent](http://twitter.com/intent/tweet/) page. With my extension I'm customising this page. Right now I first see the twitter page, then the extension is loaded and my changes to the intent page are implemented.

What I want is the opposite. I first want to load everything from the extension, so as soon as the twitter page loads it is directly visible with my custom changes implemented trough my extension.

Currently I'm using the following lines to implement the scripts/styles. Although I've got the "contentScriptWhen" set to start, this won't fix my problem..

```
include: '*',
contentScriptFile: [data.url('jq.js'), data.url('js.js')],
contentStyleFile: data.url("css.css"),
contentScriptWhen: 'start',
```

Comment: Hey man did you get a solution for this? Can you share if you did. Or can you elaborate so I can try to help you.

Comment: Hey, I've 'solved' this problem. I'm loading the Twitter Intent (TI) page in the background as soon my index page is loaded. While the TI page is loaded, it closes again. The page is in cache now, next time TI is loaded everything is instant correctly. You can find more about background loading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs

Comment: Could you post your code and explain it if possible. If I have more srcs than just the docs its nice. Would be very nice of you. I reference these topics a lot as I try to help sdk people.

Comment: In this JSFiddle the Javascript code used in my main.js is shown: http://jsfiddle.net/ronnyrr/8aBw7/2/

Comment: Thanks very much man, can you post as solution and accept your own, thats the recommended way. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've 'solved' this problem. I'm loading the Twitter Intent (TI) page in the background as soon my index page is loaded.

While the TI page is loaded, it closes again. The page is in cache now, next time TI is loaded everything is instant correctly.

You can find more about background loading here: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs)

In this fiddle is shown how I did the trick; [FIDDLE](http://bit.ly/1ly9REx)

Answer (score 0):

You can also start by preventing the document from getting parsed then on the side fetch the same document, make any modifications on the fetched document and inject it in the page. Here is what I currently use https://stackoverflow.com/a/36097573/6085033